# NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

Im trying to add admob banner to my android project using the google-play-services_lib. Im using eclipse and I have followed https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html to setup library project and no probs seen. And I add this as reference in my android project. Build is fine. But when i run it on the device, I get:

> NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil

Here is the excerpt from onCreate() method of my project:

```
int statusCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
if( statusCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
{
    Log.e("statuscode",statusCode+"");
}
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
.addTestDevice("my_device_id")
.build();
```

Further if i remove the isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() check and go to AdRequest.Builder() directly, I get the same NoClassFoundDefError now for AdRequest$Builder

Answer (score 0):

Quite clearly you have not included the pay-services library in your APK.
Follow the steps for Eclipse again from the start.